# Changing connection to SQL Server in Microsoft Access 2003 ade file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, vba

I developed an Access 2003 application that is connected to SQL Server.

My problem is that I developed the software on my server, and the application runs on the client network on a different (identical) server.

As a result my executable file (Aka. .ADE) does not open on the client's computer, because of bad SQL Server connection.

My solution so far was to open the application file (.ADP) on the client's computer, changing the connection path from there and then creating there the executable file.
Now my client has only Access runtime environment, so I cannot do such thing.

I wonder if there is a way to determine the connection in an ADE file this way.
(I know I can change it through VBA, but when the connection is initially false, I don't even get to the VBA code stage.)

Comment: If you set your connection in code in the autoexec function, then it should be executed at start up. Why would you not get to the 'VBA code stage'?

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of keeping things simple, I'll say you need to set up a testing environment *you* control that mimics your client's environment.  For instance, if they have a sql 2008 server named "SQL1", then you should install sql 2008 express on your machine, and rename your machine to "SQL1" so you can test.  You'd also need to copy the schema of their database tables and put that same schema in your own test database, and fill it with test data that is similar to theirs.  And you'll want to create duplicate logins as well.

With all that in place, I wouldn't think you'd need to update anything.  Just copy the ADE file over to your client when you're done making changes.  You could try to code your way though this scenario, but I've been there and done that.  Having a test environment that apes your client's takes a lot of headaches out of the equation.